# Rails does not fire my after_commit callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hello I have a peculiar problem. I use an after_commit callback to send notifications, but it seems the callback is not triggered at all. Simplified the situation looks like this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :do_something

  def do_something
    raise 'Doing something'
  end
end
```

Then I expected to see the raise when I open the console and create a message. But nothing happens. Furthermore rails does not even complain if I delete the 'do_something' method completely. Note that this is not a test with transactional fixtures. I even see the record committed in the db. My rails version is 3.0.9. Thanks for any help especially if it's good :-)

Edit: I learned later that the callback DID get triggered when I deployed the code to a different machine. So it must be something with my setup. Still I would appreciate your insight about what could be causing this.

Edit2: From the comments.

- The DB is MySQL so transactions are present.
- Specifying the action of the callback did not help (:on => :create).
- I need after_commit and no other callback

Comment: How you are creating the model in the console?

Comment: I tried it via a factory and also via a save and save! call.

Comment: As I understand all of them should trigger the callback. I also tried it from a production console.

Comment: Try logging in your `after_commit` instead of `raising`.  Rails rescues nil from any `after_commit` hook being called.

Comment: It's not your fault, it's [a bug in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3205)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

David mentioned the explanation for this behavior in the questions comment.

[Transaction Callbacks documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks)

> "If any exceptions are raised within one of these  callbacks, they will
>   be ignored so that they don't interfere with the other callbacks. As
>   such, if your  callback code could raise an exception, you'll need  to
>   rescue it and handle it appropriately within the callback."

see also:

- [Rails Github Issue 3205](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3205)
- [Pull request #11123](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11123)

Answer (score 7):

One possible cause (at least on 5.0) is:

```
after_commit :do_something, on: :create
after_commit :do_something, on: :destroy
```

here `do_something` is referenced twice, and none will be executed. Once it is combined to

```
after_commit :do_something, on: [:create, :destroy]
```

it would be called again.

Comment: For 4.0 the last declared after_commit will work. In this case the destroy.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to put a patch in your spec/support to enable after_commit callbacks when using transactional fixtures.  If you are using transaction fixtures then a commit doesn't actually ever happen.

The patch: https://gist.github.com/charleseff/1305285

Comment: The Gist is already packed as gem and working too https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the action when this after_commit must be triggered....

The after_commit is basically used in those Databases where the concept of transaction is present...So try the following code...

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_commit :do_something, :on => [:create, :update, :destroy]

 def do_something
  raise 'Doing something'
 end
end
```

Comment: Thought so too, but it didn't help.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that the DB is MySQL.

Comment: I think it should not matter a lot becoz MySQL and Sqlite both support the transactions and if it is not running on MySQL then it would not run SQLite also...but still you can give it a try and let me know the results...

Answer (score 0):

Try if below code helps -

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_commit :do_something, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]

 def do_something
  raise 'Doing something'
 end
end
```

Comment: Nno, this did not help. See the second edit of the question. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You have the following:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :do_something

  def do_something
    puts 'Doing something'
  end
end
```

You may try with `after_create` or `after_save` depending on your needs.

after_commits just execute when the record is sucessfully saved in database, because save, save! and destroy runs within transactions.

As found in documentation: [Active Record Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Comment: I specifically need after_commit, because after_create can get executed BEFORE the record is actually committed in the db so that the other connections can also read it. And if you send a notification to some other device with an id of the record and the record is not yet there -> nothing happens.